# How to add media file(video) in infowindows in google map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to add media file(Video) in infowindow in google map.
What would be the easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**WORKING DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Xk6Uu/)
You can actually insert any HTML snippet here. My demo uses a Youtube iframe, of course you can use HTML5 video tag instead.

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Video in Info Window</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<iframe width="640" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/a8UOzBUZxCw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });
```

See my [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Xk6Uu/1/) with your own video embedded.

Comment: I do not have to use youtube link for showing the video, If there is a video file in my directory then how it will be rendered?

Comment: @RaviMishra see my updated demo with your own video. Just replace the source with your own file and path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `YouTube Video` as the media file in Google Map' Infowindow.
Check this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/DHxExx5QjsA

And Hope this sample code will give an idea about your requirement.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4222685, -111.8226402)
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions)
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4222685, -111.8226402);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UmFjNiiVk9w?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
        })
        bubble.open(map, marker);
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
  <div id="map" style="width: 984px; height: 495px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not have to use youtube link for showing the video, If there is a video file in my directory then how it will be rendered?